# RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL when trying to access USB device

Tags: c#, windows, exception

I have this piece of code:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");              
foreach (var queryObj in searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>()) //Error points to this line
```

Basically what this code does is, it runs through a list of connected devices and looks if the one i want is connected.
If I run this code while the device is already connected at the time when the code is ran, then it works flawlessly.
But if I trigger this code with DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL (which is event the system sends when some device is connected and i catch it with

```
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if(..DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL..) 
        new ScanDevices(); /*Here lies the code from above (in the class)*/
}
```

I get this error:

An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)).

If I put thread.sleep(5000) on top of the code above, so it waits 5 seconds before executing, then the code works. So the conflict must be somewhere, where other things try to access that device first and hog it all for themselves.

I searched the internet and found suggestions like sending custom postmessage to myself to trigger the code, but I have little idea on how to do that, or even how would that solved the problem.

What is the best solution here?

Comment: It is a problem that's induced by threading.  Your question doesn't mention any detail at all about what kind of threads you create or what kind of app this is (console vs gui).  Details that matter a lot.

Comment: I do not work with threads at all in that application. It is WPF application.

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your code in a new thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Device present: " + currentObject);          
        ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
        serial = theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join(); //wait for the thread to finish
```